# ExclusiveLock vs MinimalLock

Tags: c#, log4net

I have C# functions passed as callback to dynamic library functions created in C++. I suppose these callbacks might be called from different threads. Callback functions are using logger:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog _Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Programm just crash when I turn on logging in callback functions with logging model:

```
<_lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

And works fine and even faster when I use:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+ExclusiveLock" />
```

I suppose in my case `MinimalLock` is enough since no file rolling is performing. I'm wrong? How to explane programm slowdown in `MinimalLock` case?

```
    <appender name="DebugLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
        <param name="File" value="./WrpLog/" />
        <_lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+ExclusiveLock" />

        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value="Debu\g.yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
            <_levelMin value="INFO" />
            <_levelMax value="OFF" />
            <levelMin value="ALL" />
            <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %m /// %c%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using minimal lock, log4net gets a lock on the file when you write to the file. This will be done on each log message. When you have a Exclusive lock the file stays locked all the time, and you do not need to reopen the file. The exclusive lock will have better performance, but you can not open/write to the file from an other location. The minimal lock will allow you to write to one file from multiple locations, however as you have seen the performance is much worse as the Exclusive lock.

Comment: This means both logging types are thread safe and none of them is more safer?

Comment: They have tot be, but if your crash is caused by log4net (log4net is throwing) then I would like to see the steps you take to cause that. Because log4net is not supposed to crash your application.